# Magnolia could not be started java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: magnolia

I am running an magnolia Application using magnolia-blossom.

I have added this dependency jar below :

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-module-standard-templating-kit</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
      <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
```

I am getting the error :

> Oops, Magnolia could not be started java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:info/magnolia/dam/provider/AssetProviderNotFoundException

for which Tomcat server is unable to start.

Can anyone suggest me that how can i resolve this Error.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing Magnolia DAM, use this dependency snippet:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia.dam</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-dam</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I found the version used by STK 2.7 by looking at its POM here https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/repositories/magnolia.public.releases/info/magnolia/standard-templating-kit-parent/2.7/standard-templating-kit-parent-2.7.pom